# iOS multiple API Calls for single VC - best practice

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, api, nsoperation

Im using Swift 3.0, I have a requirement where my VC displays screen based on 4API calls. Other VC has 2 API Calls

As of now i created a background thread and running it serially. There is no dependence on other API calls. All are independent

I somehow feel that this is not right way. Searched forum's but couldnt find exact answer

What is the best practice that i can use to call all 4 API's ?

using GCD Parallel queues or with NSOperation ? Pls Advice

Comment: Are you familiar with using `DispatchGroup`?  Maybe that is relevant?

Comment: Are you caching the info locally or ??

Comment: Everytime the screen loads, it calls API (because info is updating real time) ..so I believe no caching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Dispatch group and call all api parallel. 
Once all executions are finished you can use notify method to perform other task.

```
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
      print("All async calls were finished, do our stuff here")
    }
```